# How to install luarocks in Cent OS?

Tags: lua, centos, luarocks

I tried to install luarocks in Cent OS.
After `./configure` command I get error:

```
Lua interpreter found: /bin/lua...
Lua version detected: 5.1
lua found in $PATH: /bin
Checking Lua includes... lua.h not found (looked in //include, //include/lua/5.1, //include/lua5.1)
You may want to use the flag --with-lua or --with-lua-include. See --help.
```

As I understand correctly, at first I need install Lua and specify path to Lua when configure luarocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the Lua interpreter in `/bin` (and not `/usr/bin`) seems unusual.

Do you have the file `lua.h` installed somewhere? (In other words, did you install the Lua development headers?) You should be able to find it using the `locate` command:

```
locate lua.h
```

If you do have `lua.h` (for example, in `/usr/include`), tell the configure script where this file is located, just like the error message is suggesting you:

```
./configure --with-lua-include=/usr/include
```

Comment: Could this be because of the [UsrMerge](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/)? Should the LuaRocks `configure` script check for that?

Comment: It could be. Oh well, GoboLinux has had /usr/bin and /bin (and /sbin, and /usr/bin) merged since 2003 and we never had problems with that. I need to do a major rewrite of the `configure` script at some point. There's a number of corner cases where it gets it wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you know your lua version and then locate the header files.

for checking you lua version just type:

```
lua -v
```

I had to install both lua and lua-devel(for the lua.h headers)

```
sudo dnf install lua lua-devel
```

then I update plocate database to search for the header files:

```
updatedb
plocate lua.h
```

the command returned

```
/usr/include/lua.h
/usr/include/lua.hpp
```

The second problem installing it was the versions, the default looks for 5.1 but the dnf installed lua 5.4, so I had to specify the version:

```
./configure --lua-version=5.4 --with-lua-include=/usr/local/include
```

**Then it worked.**

In my case when I tried to install lua and luarocks from dnf I got the error ( I am using fedora workstation 36):

```
Error: Failed finding Lua header files. You may need to install them or configure LUA_INCDIR.
```